# Apache Ignite sql query returns only cache contents, not complete results from database

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database

My Ignite nodes (2 server nodes - let's call them A and B) are configured as follows:

```
ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);
ccfg.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
ccfg.setWriteBehindBatchSize(10000);
```

Node A is started first, from command line as follows:

`apache-ignite-fabric-2.2.0-bin>bin/ignite.bat config/default-config.xml`

Node B is started from java code by running

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(ServerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration());
    ignite.cache("MyCache").loadCache(null);
...
}
```

(jar containing ServerConfigurationFactory is put in the apache-ignite-fabric-2.2.0-bin\libs directory so Node A and B are on the same cluster..otherwise there is an error)

I have a query that is supposed to return 9061 results from the database. After the cache loading process in Node B, I went to the Web Console and ran a simple count SQL statement against the caches. There is a button "Execute on selected node" that allows you to choose a specific cache to query. I queried Node A and got a count of 2341, and on Node B I get a count of 2064. If I just use the "Execute" button I get 4405 which is just the total of node A and B. Obviously they are missing 4656 records (9061 total records in db - 4405 in nodes A and B). I also ran the same count query in Java code using `SqlFieldsQuery` and I also get 4405.

Since readThrough is set to `true` I expected Ignite to also return results that are not in memory. But this is not the case because it just returns whatever is on the cache. Am I doing something wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read though works only for key-value APIs, so SQL engine assumes that all required data is preloaded from database prior to running a query.

If your data set doesn't fit in memory and you can't preload all the data, you can use native Ignite persistence storage: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Comment: I see. Does the read-through/write-through/write-behind all apply to key-value API only? If I am only using 3rd party persistence then it is useless to configure those parameters?

Comment: Regarding data fitting in memory: they are just 9061 records and I have 16GB of RAM. What's also interesting is when I set `CacheMode` to `CacheMode.LOCAL`, for a larger table (200k records), *all* records were actually loaded to memory (running the count query yields the correct total). I think this proves that it isn't an issue of data not fitting in memory. Is there any configuration I can set to guarantee that Ignite loads as much as possible into memory in `CacheMode.PARTITIONED` mode?

Comment: Yes, read/write-through is applicable only to key-value APIs in case 3rd party persistence is used. You should use `IgniteCache#loadCache` to load the data from the cache store: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading#ignitecacheloadcache